# Incompatibility between memoir settrimmedsize and PDF-X?

Tags: luatex, memoir, pdfx

I'm trying to generate a pdf-x with `pdfx`package.

If I compile the following mwe with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstocksize{29.7cm}{21cm}
\settrimmedsize{21cm}{13cm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{*}{9.1cm}{1.618}
\setlrmargins{1.5cm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{2.12cm}{*}{2}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

the layout gets messed up. It seems that the problem is between `pdfx` and `memoir`'s `\settrimmedsize`: if I set the trimmed size identical with the stock size, the problem disappears.

As a matter of fact, the problem disappears also when I generate pdf type a-1b (with `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}`).

Does anyone have an idea where the issue come from, and how to fix it?

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with lualatex and xelatex (it won't harm but is unneeded.)

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. Yes, I'll edit the mwe according to your indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdfx doesn't take memoir's dimensions into account and uses \paperwidth instead of \stockwidth for the mediabox. You can reset this like this (with lualatex and pdflatex, xelatex needs different code), but you probably will have to adapt the values of the other boxes too--I simply copied the values currently used by pdfx.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstocksize{29.7cm}{21cm}
\settrimmedsize{21cm}{13cm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{*}{9.1cm}{1.618}
\setlrmargins{1.5cm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{2.12cm}{*}{2}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:Nx
\pdfpagesattr
  {
    /MediaBox[0~0~\dim_to_decimal:n{0.996264009963\stockwidth}~\dim_to_decimal:n{0.996264009963\stockheight}]
    /BleedBox[0~0~\dim_to_decimal:n{0.996264009963\stockwidth}~\dim_to_decimal:n{0.996264009963\stockheight}]
    /CropBox[0~0~\dim_to_decimal:n{0.996264009963\stockwidth}~\dim_to_decimal:n{0.996264009963\stockheight}]
    /TrimBox[25~20~\dim_to_decimal:n{0.996264009963\stockwidth-25pt}~\dim_to_decimal:n{0.996264009963\stockheight-20pt}]
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff   
   
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @UlrikeFischer! It works for me without adapting anything. Just a question, if I can: what does the number 0.996264009963 mean? I would expect just `\stockwidth`... Doesn't it imply any resizing, does it?

Comment: the values in the pdf are in bp, the number is the ratio 72/72,27, so the difference between bp and pt.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks again!